# How to Convert List To JsonObject?

Tags: java, android, json

This may to possible of duplicate i need to convert the list to jsonobject like this

```
{"EmailID":"Djlj@sl.com","PhoneNumber":"870796850","ID":2}
```

like this how can i achieve this so far what i have tried is :

```
 List<CustomerModel> listobj=new ArrayList<CustomerModel>();
    listobj=timetrackerdaoobj.Listtoserver();
            String gsonString=new Gson().toJson(listobj, collectionType);
```

In this method am getting jsonarray like this

```
[{"EmailID":"Djlj@sl.com","PhoneNumber":"870796850","ID":2}]
```

But i need format like this:

```
{"EmailID":"Djlj@sl.com","PhoneNumber":"870796850","ID":2}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way,

```
 String gsonString=new Gson().toJson(listobj, collectionType);
 gsonString = gsonString.replace("[","").replace("]","");
 System.out.println(gsonString);   // here you got expected answer
```

this may helps you.

Comment: kindly mark as answer . then only users find correct answer easily

Comment: This is a working answer, but it is not a good answer. Accepting it would confuse future readers

Comment: Then which is better @ankitagrawal

Comment: should i post a answer @MedlinMoni

Comment: yaaaa if u have better means please do it

Answer (score 0):

You want a JSON Object, and not a JSON Array. So pass only your java object and not the list into your Gson converter :

```
String gsonString = new Gson().toJson(listobj.get(0), yourType);
```